# Adding Gedmo Sortable to existing repository

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

I've added Gedmo Sortable to an existing repository which previously used the Nested extension, however this proved to be unstable for our needs.

Since I've added the Sortable extension, added the listeners, etc, the positions of the records don't updated correctly. For example, when moving the second item within a group I end up with something like 1, 1, 3, 4, 5.

This only appears to happen when there is already data within the related table.

For the code, you'd be best off looking at the Gedmo example as reference as the code is pretty much exactly the same.

I've tried setting the sortable group to null, flushing then readding all the items back, but that doesn't work either...

Any ideas folk?

Cheers!